# Space in tableau project name causing issue when trying remote tabcmd command

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to refresh a tableau extract remotely from a linux box using the command :

```
./tableau_script.bash refreshextracts --server servername --username username --Password password --project <project name with spaces> --workbook <workbook with spaces>
```

tableau_script.bash is a bash script with the java call to tabcmd class.
The issue I face is with the spaces in the workbook or project ,could not find any way to escape this ,tried `\`,`%20`,`%%20` but none seems to work.
Any suggestions.

Comment: I'm sure you tried this, but just to be sure -- did you try enclosing the project name in single quotes?

Comment: Yes tried that does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose project name with this "\"

Comment: Enclosing the name with backslashes will do nothing.  The spaces need to be escaped with backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to escape the spaces.

```
 ./tableau_script.bash refreshextracts --server servername --username username --Password password --project project\ name\ with\ spaces --workbook workbook\ with\ spaces
```